# How to catch params with React Navigation 5?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

UPDATE: I did solve this which you can see in my comments shortly after posting.  I am keeping this up in case it helps others or if anyone has a better approach or method.

My goal is to pass params to the next Screen.  I will show how I have done it without React Navigation 5 so you can see my goal:

I have a button from one screen like so:

```
<Button
    title="View Card"
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("CardDetail", {cardId: 1})}
/>
```

This takes me to the other screen CardDetail:

I show the cardId:

```
class CardDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{this.props.route.params.cardId}</Text>
                <Text>Card Detail </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, I have implemented React Navigation but cannot find a way to catch the params.  Here is what I have:

```
function Overview({props}) {
    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Overview</Text>
        <Text>{prop}</Text> // this doesn't work
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

class CardDetail extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
             <Tab.Navigator>
                 <Tab.Screen name="Overview" component={Overview} />
             </Tab.Navigator>
        );
    }
}
```

I have tried a few ways:  Here is one

```
function Overview({props}) {
    const cardId = React.useState(this.props.route.params.cardId);
    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Overview</Text>
        <Text>{cardId}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Tried adding:

```
<Tab.Screen name="Overview" component={Overview} options={{ title: this.props.route.params.cardId }} />
```

This error: `label is not a function`

**Tried doing this method:** This seems like its the most promising
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/
function Overview(props) {
const cardId = this.props.route.params.cardId;
console.log("sadf", props);
return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
Overview
{cardId}

);
}

```
            <Tab.Screen name="Overview">
                {props => <Overview {...this.props}  />}
            </Tab.Screen>
```

This seems promising but I cannot find a way to actually have it pass to the Overview.

I have tried passing props through: `const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator({props});` a handful of ways.  Either nothing happens or it tells me my method isn't accepted in RN5

Am I even attempting this correctly?

I've read through the docs of RN5 and tried many ways to pass the params

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/

Comment: I was able to get the prop passed with: `{props => <Overview {...this.props}  />}` and instead of a function used `const Overview = props => {`

Comment: Going to leave this question up incase it helps others or someone has a more efficient way

Comment: Is it the first time that your component OverView is shown ? Becase it might happen that it was opened previously and now when it opens up again, it just shows up the previously rendered part which may have not been unmounted at that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That so easy
First: When you pass params CardDetail(Now is tabbar) that mean your params is props of CardDetail

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

class CardDetail extends Component {
    const cardId = this.props.route.params.cardId
    render() {
        return(
             <Tab.Navigator>
                 // ==> and pass cardId into Overview as props
                 <Tab.Screen name="Overview" component={() => <Overview cardId={cardId}/>} />
             </Tab.Navigator>
        );
    }
}
```

In Overview component just use cardId like that

```
function Overview(props) {
    const {cardId} = props;
    return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Overview</Text>
        <Text>{cardId}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```